# How can i configure this milestone in HighStock

Tags: highcharts

How can i configure points that i showed on below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The highlighted part is a [Navigator](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/navigator). Navigator series could be adjusted in [`navigator.series`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.series).

Simple demo from API reference: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/navigator/series/